# C++ cout cin string manipulation

Tags: c++, string, cout, cin

I'm trying to get a line as input from the command line. My problem is that I'm not getting the whole line, but it's being tokenized by space.

So if I entered something such as "I like Math a lot" instead of getting

```
"you enterend: I like Math a lot"
```

I get the follwoing:

```
EDITING MODE: Enter a command
i like Math a lot
you entered i

EDITING MODE: Enter a command
you entered like

EDITING MODE: Enter a command
you entered Math

EDITING MODE: Enter a command
you entered a

EDITING MODE: Enter a command
you entered lot


void enterEditingMode(){
    editingMode = TRUE;
    static string CMD = "\nEDITING MODE: Enter a command\n";
    string input;
    while(editingMode == TRUE){
        cout << CMD;
        cin >> input;
        //we assume input is always correct
        // here we need to parse the instruction
        cout << "you entered " << input <<endl;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::getline` is the standard way to read a line of input at a time.

You can use it like this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, string);
```

It returns a reference to the input stream which has an implicit conversion to `void*` so you can check for success easily like this:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, string))
{
    // successfully read a line...
}
```

Comment: And don't forget the cin.getline(char*, int) version if you want to take in a c string.

Comment: It does not have an explicit conversion to void*. It has an explicit conversion to an unspecified type that is usable in a Boolean context. It may happen to be void* in your implementation but that may not hold across all. And its a lot easier to explain to beginners that the result is convertible to something that acts like a boolean.

Comment: Actually, `operator void*` is required by the standard. It's part of the `basic_ios` base class interface.

Answer (score 1):

`cin.getline(input);`

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/ for more info.

Comment: The `istream` member functions called `getline` all take `char` buffers and a length, not a `string`.

Comment: I tried this already, the problem is that since the code is in a while loop, at first it reads the new line character. So I always get "you entered" when I don't even enter anything.