# Use of size() in c++

Tags: c++, size

hre is the program. I want to change all the "a" to "A". but when I pass a string of more than one word. (example: very good) it only takes the first word

I understand the use of Replace(), but I want to try something from scratch, I am very new in this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string asesToUpperCase(string word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)

            if (word[i] == 'a')  word[i] = 'A';

    return word;
}

int main()
{
    string aword;
    cout << "enter a word: ";
    cin >> aword;

   cout << asesToUpperCase(aword);


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete compilable example with expected output and actual output.

Comment: is your title anyway related to your problem statement?

Comment: What do you actually mean _"but when I use a string with more than one word"_? Can you demonstrate/reproduce this behavior in a [minimal compilable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: The function should work. You're probably passing in only the first word.

Comment: The function you're looking for is `std::replace`. Use that instead of reinventing it. Anyway, crystal ball: `cin >> myString;`

Comment: example: input fail, output fAil

Comment: Do you need to change the same string? Or you need strictly to return a copy leaving original (source) string unchanged?
In case you need to alter source string better pass NOT (string word), but (string &word). Passing by reference will decrease the amount of unneeded allocating/copy/deallocating memory operations.

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo: That's an example of when it works. We need to see a complete program that demonstrates when it *doesn't* work. Something along the lines of `string s = "abc abc"; cout << asesToUpperCase(s) << "\n";` (which works correctly when I try it, BTW).

Comment: ok, I will add the whole program

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo Aside your edits came up a bit too late now, adding your whole program might not be the best idea. Just reduce it to a reproducible sample that works the same way with this function.

Comment: I see you've just edited the question. Are you going to edit it again to show us the whole program? Your clarification is not helpful. As far as I can tell, your function should work; you're probably calling it incorrectly.

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo A debugging tip: if a function is giving you unexpected output, check the input that you're giving it is correct. Just print out the value of the argument you're passing to the function. I'm 99.9% certain that it is incorrect in your case.

Comment: @AbdelHidalgo `cin >> aword;` just captured up the first _word_ entered, you need `std::getline(cin,aword);` to read all the input.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1736080/827263. (I've nominated this question for re-opening; if it's re-opened, I suggest closing it again as a duplicate of the above).

Comment: thanks to everybody, I wasn't expecting such fast answers, apologies for not being properly prepared for this. The problem was in the getline command that I didn't use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you use `operator >>` to enter several words in one string. Use standard function `std::getline` instead.
Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::replace` that does the job.

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::replace( word.begin(), word.end(), 'a', 'A' );
```

Comment: You may be right, but there's no evidence of that in the question. I suggest waiting until the OP gives us enough information.

Comment: @Keith Thompson He can give the information in the next day.:) I am not going to wait such period of time.:)

Comment: No need to wait; just don't answer at all.

Comment: i am here, just give me a minute

Comment: @Keith Thompson Why have not I to answer? I give the answer relevant to the existent question.

Comment: How is it relevant? I don't see any uses of `>>` in the question.

Comment: @Keith Thompson It is just your personal problem.

Comment: There is nothing personal about this. (If it were just me, my initial comment wouldn't have gotten 4 upvotes.)

Comment: keith I want to wait until I see more answer, thank you for yours

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't agree that this is Keith's personal problem, I have this also. As I solved the problem in my comment, you see your proposed changes wouldn't have helped anyways :P ...

Comment: @Abdel Hidalgo You will not see any more answer because the question put in hold. So If you indeed use operator >> to enter several words in one string then substitute it for std::getline. Or at least print out the word before calling the function that to be sure that the string indeed contains several words.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I do not see where you "solved" the problem. You simply wrote the same as I wrote in my answer but after me. So my answer is very useful.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've just been waiting to be sure, after the OP posted his edit.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ As I said it is your and Keith Thompson's problem. Why do you try your problems to pass on me? If you have some doubts then they are your doubts not my

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have at least to commit, that I could have been distracted too much by your bold mentioning of `std::replace()` in first place, and not showing how to use `std::getline()` in conjunction with the OP's function, that should have been working as intended from the very beginning of this discourse.