# Strange cout behavior in a while loop in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to print the input and then all the strings in the tk vector, as in the following program:

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        string input;
        cout << "prompt: ";
        cin >> input;
        vector<string> tk = {"this", "is", "an", "example"}; 

        cout << input << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < tk.size(); i++) {
            cout << tk[i] << endl;
        }

    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

When I give the input "Hello world" I am expecting the output to be:

```
Hello world
this
is
an 
example
prompt:
```

But the output was:

```
Hello
this
is
an
example
prompt: world
this
is 
an
example
prompt:
```

Does anyone know what went wrong here? I guess the cause is related to how the buffer works, but I really have no idea about the details.

Comment: This comes up on SO daily. People keep forgetting (or they didn't read their C++ book properly!) that `>>` into a string gets _a word_. Surely there's a FAQ for this "problem"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ cout cin string manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736080/c-cout-cin-string-manipulation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming into a string with `>>` reads a single word, up to a whitespace character. So you get two separate inputs, `"Hello"` and `"world"`.

To read an entire line:

```
getline(cin, input);
```

Comment: @dkg: No, that would read the entire stream (up to end-of-file or an error), and wouldn't give you a string.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer works OK. The logic behind `opreator>>` is ... ummm... a little bit complicated. You are in fact using a free standing `operator>>` for input stream and a string - [this no (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

The key part is:

> [...] then reads characters [...] until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> [...]
>
> - `std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).

Which means it "eats" input until a white space (according to current locale) is met. Of course as Mike said, for the whole line, there is `getline`.

It's worth to remember this nitpick too: [Why does cin command leaves a '\n' in the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109679/why-does-cin-command-leaves-a-n-in-the-buffer/28109827#28109827)